# SwiftUICharts are not redrawn when given new data

Tags: swiftui

I am adding the possibility to swipe in order to update a barchart. What I want to show is statistics for different station. To view different station I want the user to be able to swipe between the stations. I can see that the swiping works and each time I swipe I get the correct data from my controller. The problem is that my view is not redrawn properly.

I found [this guide](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swiftui-state-management-guide/), but cannot make it work.

Say I swipe right from station 0 with data `[100, 100, 100]` to station 2, the retrieved data from my controller is `[0.0, 100.0, 0.0]`. The view I have still is for `[`100, 100, 100]`.

[image]

The station number is correctly updated, so I suspect it needs some state somehow.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUICharts

struct DetailedResultsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    @State private var tabIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var startPos: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var isSwiping = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Station \(viewModel.getStation() + 1)")
            TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
                BarCharts(data: viewModel.getData(kLatestRounds: 10, station: viewModel.getStation()), disciplineName: viewModel.getName()).tabItem { Group {
                    Image(systemName: "chart.bar")
                    Text("Last 10 Sessions")
                }}.tag(0)
            }
        }.gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged { gesture in
                if self.isSwiping {
                    self.startPos = gesture.location
                    self.isSwiping.toggle()
                }
            }
            .onEnded { gesture in
                if gesture.location.x - startPos.x > 10 {
                    viewModel.decrementStation()
                }
                if gesture.location.x - startPos.x < -10 {
                    viewModel.incrementStation()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

struct BarCharts: View {
    var data: [Double]
    var title: String
    init(data: [Double], disciplineName: String) {
        self.data = data
        title = disciplineName
        print(data)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            BarChartView(data: ChartData(points: self.data), title: self.title, style: Styles.barChartStyleOrangeLight, form: CGSize(width: 300, height: 400))
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var station = 1
    let controller = DetailedViewController()
    var isPreview = false

    func getData(kLatestRounds: Int, station: Int) -> [Double] {
        if isPreview {
            return [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
        } else {
            let data = controller.getResults(kLatestRounds: kLatestRounds, station: station, fileName: userDataFile)
            return data
        }
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        controller.getDiscipline().name
    }

    func getNumberOfStations() -> Int {
        controller.getDiscipline().getNumberOfStations()
    }

    func getStation() -> Int {
        station
    }

    func incrementStation() {
        station = (station + 1) % getNumberOfStations()
    }

    func decrementStation() {
        station -= 1
        if station < 0 {
            station = getNumberOfStations() - 1
        }
    }
}
```

The data is printed inside the constructor each time I swipe. Shouldn't that mean it should be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t use SwiftUICharts so I can’t test it, but the least you can try is manually set the id to the view

```
struct DetailedResultsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    @State private var tabIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var startPos: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var isSwiping = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Station \(viewModel.getStation() + 1)")
            TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
                BarCharts(data: viewModel.getData(kLatestRounds: 10, station: viewModel.getStation()), disciplineName: viewModel.getName())
                .id(viewmodel.station) // here. If it doesn’t work, you can set it to the whole TabView
                .tabItem { Group {
                    Image(systemName: "chart.bar")
                    Text("Last 10 Sessions")
                }}.tag(0)
            }
        }.gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged { gesture in
                if self.isSwiping {
                    self.startPos = gesture.location
                    self.isSwiping.toggle()
                }
            }
            .onEnded { gesture in
                if gesture.location.x - startPos.x > 10 {
                    viewModel.decrementStation()
                }
                if gesture.location.x - startPos.x < -10 {
                    viewModel.incrementStation()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind elaborating on what the problem was nad/or where to read more about it? 

Putting it in the `TabView` worked.

Comment: You can always set explicit ID to a view and if the ID changes, the whole ID gets recreated as it is a completely “new View” (you can look for view identity). If it worked only for TabView then it probably means that TabView could have some issues with non-static content? Or that it doesn’t update it for some reason. It’s worth further testing. When you set an explicit ID to the TabView, the new one was created after the change, so that is why it changed the data

Comment: Thank you, requires patience and practise to learn all the "subtle" things that happens in SwiftUI.